# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

When opening a portal on WordPress, an error appears in the header.php file -

> syntax error, unexpected end of file in header.php .

I tried changing the code and leaving only the header in the condition, but that didn't help either.

Relevant code:

```
<?php if (get_field('is_header_absolute_position')) { ?>
        <header class="position_absolute">
    <?php } else { ?>
        <header>
    <?php } ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__wrap">
                
                    <?php if (pll_current_language('slug') == "en") { ?>
                        <?php $logo = get_field('logo_en', 'option');
                        if( !empty($logo) ): ?>
                            <a href="/en/" class="logo_wrap">
                                <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo['alt']; ?>">
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php $logo = get_field('logo', 'option');
                        if( !empty($logo) ): ?>
                            <a href="/" class="logo_wrap">
                                <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logo['alt']; ?>">
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                <nav class="menu head_menu">
                    <?php if (pll_current_language('slug') == "en") { ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header_menu_eng', 'menu_class'=>'', 'container' => 'ul')); ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header_menu', 'menu_class'=>'', 'container' => 'ul')); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </nav>
                <nav class="menu mobile_menu">
                    <?php if (pll_current_language('slug') == "en") { ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header_menu_eng', 'menu_class'=>'', 'container' => 'ul')); ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header_menu', 'menu_class'=>'', 'container' => 'ul')); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </nav>
                <button class="toggle_mnu">
                    <?php if (pll_current_language('slug') == "en") { ?>
                        <?php if (get_field('mobile_menu_text_en', 'option')) { ?>
                            <span class="toggle_mnu_text"><?php the_field('mobile_menu_text_en', 'option'); ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php if (get_field('mobile_menu_text', 'option')) { ?>
                            <span class="toggle_mnu_text"><?php the_field('mobile_menu_text', 'option'); ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <span class="sandwich">
                        <span class="sw-topper"></span>
                        <span class="sw-bottom"></span>
                        <span class="sw-footer"></span>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</header> <-Here it says that there is an error. This is the end of the file
```

I tried to find a solution, but I couldn’t find one that fits this

Comment: My PHP installation sees no parse errors in that code.

Comment: Please dont use an error message as the title

Comment: I don't see any issues. Normally that error is due to something like unclosed braces for if/else statements, but there's 12 of each. My PHP IDE doesn't see any syntax errors, either. Maybe you have a bad invisible character somewhere?

Comment: Also, the error mentions line 193, but there's only 56 lines in the code you've given us, so I'm definitely leaning towards bad invisible characters or line endings.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will be glad you took the time in the end.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are not using right PHP blocks. Just try with a simple test

Try like this, I have tested at my end and it worked fine

[Click on this image to get code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SJqd.png)

Comment: Images of code help no one. Code answers should be in code blocks. And how does your answer differ from the original code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).